# String End with Character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server 2012 with 2 million records. I am trying to find all those records which is not ending with character as in example.

Code:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(
     ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
     MYVAL VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT @TABLE
VALUES ('4639016:42:'),
       ('3279022:42:'),
       ('4605907:42:XY'),
       ('4190078:42:ZS')
```

Code I used:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @TABLE 
WHERE MYVAL NOT LIKE '%:[A-Z]'
```

but it's not returning the correct result.

I also want to pull all those records only which are ending with ':'

Can someone please share your expertise?

Thanks

Comment: You have a stray `:` in your `LIKE` clause (i.e. should be `NOT LIKE '%[A-Z]'`)

Comment: select * from @TABLE where right(MYVAL, 1) like '[A-Z]'

Comment: Based on your example, what records do you want to return? You state that you want to return all records not ending with a character but you also want to pull all records ending with ":".  What about "adfasdf~~~~", so that it doesn't end with a "character" but it also doesn't contain a ":"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `RIGHT` to get last character:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @TABLE
WHERE RIGHT(MYVAL,1) != ':';
-- RIGHT(MYVAL,1) LIKE '[A-Z]'
```

Comment: I know this will return the right records, but for 2 million rows, will this not be a hard RBAR operation? For that many records, a function (`right()`) and an inequality comparison will hit performance, won't it?

Comment: @Shawn  Searching for last character using `RIGHT` or `col LIKE '%[A-Z]` is not SARGable so index on column MyVal(if exists) would not be utilized. Please note that full table scan is not strictly the same as RBAR. Of course OP should store values after `:` in different column and avoid text operations.